# Does Spring 3 work with Acegi Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm currently trying to migrate an application that uses old technologies (Java 5, Spring 2.5, Hibernate 3, Acegi Security, etc.) to newer technologies.

However, I want to do it step by step so that I won't face tons of problems without knowing where they come from. So far, I've only managed to upgrade to Java 7.

Now, I'd like to migrate to Spring 3.2, but I don't know if my application will run with Spring 3.2 and Acegi Security without major changes. Now I know that I should use Spring Security instead, but as I said, I want to migrate step by step.

Thanks

Comment: I do not see any problem

Comment: Acegi hasn't been updated for years and has known security holes. Your app will be likely be vulnerable until you update to Spring Security so you would probably be better to do that at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably work, they are not that tightly coupled as Spring Security

Comment: Good stuff. Now I would seriously suggest you look at upgrading to Spring Security 3.0.x anytime soon as the platform has been much improved